# Design php output table with css

Tags: php, html, css, oracle

Please anyone who can help me with this problem. I have a html file with a question. When submit is clicked it calls a php(which is connected with my database in Oracle) and it shows a table inside the html (using ajax).
I would like to know how can i show that table in a nicer form? Can I design it?

Here is my code in php

```
    <?php
    {
    session_start();
    include "connect.php";
    }
    $conn = DBConnect();
    $stid = DBExecute($conn, "select something...");
    $total = 0;
    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name1</th>
    <th>Name2</th>
    </tr>";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['something'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['something'];
    echo "</td>";

    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

and I want to have for example this css instructions for the table i will show...

```
        #newspaper-a
        {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #69c;
        }
        #newspaper-a th
        {
    padding: 12px 17px 12px 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #039;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #69c;
        }
        #newspaper-a td
        {
    padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
    color: #669;
        }
        #newspaper-a tbody tr:hover td
        {
    color: #339;
    background: #d0dafd;
        }
```

Please does anyone know what should i do to succeed it??? 
Important the table will be shown inside the same page not in another one..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your ID to the table div - like this:

```
<?php
{
session_start();
include "connect.php";
}
$conn = DBConnect();
$stid = DBExecute($conn, "select something...");
$total = 0;
// ADD YOUR ID HERE vvvvvvvv
echo "<table id="newspaper-a"> 
<tr>
<th>Name1</th>
<th>Name2</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['something'];
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $row['something'];
echo "</td>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jakemulley/hs3mF/